# repeat expression several times in R

Tags: r

In R, I want to find out the effect of character string length on computation time of a certain operation. For this, I need random character strings of different lengths. All I can think of now is:

```
cases1 <- letters[sample(15)]
cases2 <- paste(letters[sample(15)], letters[sample(15)], sep="")
cases3 <- paste(letters[sample(15)], letters[sample(15)], letters[sample(15)], sep="")
```

How do I automate that?
I don't want to keep copypasting...
Or does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 n <- 3
 do.call(`paste0`,as.data.frame(replicate(n, letters[sample(15)])))
```

If you want say `1:3`

```
 n1 <- 1:3
 lapply(n1, function(.n) do.call(`paste0`,
    as.data.frame(replicate(.n, letters[sample(15)]))))
```

Or as @Berry showed in the comments

```
 apply(replicate(3, letters[sample(15)]), MARGIN=1, paste, collapse="")
```

Comment: Oh Yes. replicate is exactly what I need!! Thanks for making my day!

Comment: People scared of do.call might want also want to try `apply(replicate(3, letters[sample(15)]), MARGIN=1, paste, collapse="")`